# Preventing the creating of .ropeproject when using "Rename Symbol" in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, rope

I'm using VSCode, with the Python extension.

When renaming symbols (using `rope`), a folder called `.ropeproject` is created; I don't want this. I know that to prevent this from happening, I need to pass `None` to `rope`. However, I don't know how to pass additional arguments to `rope` using VSCode's "Rename Symbol" function.

Any ideas?